# Segue Won't Pass Data Onto TableView

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview, segue

I am trying to set an array in another view controller, named BillTrackerViewController, to the values of an NSMutableArray called billtrackertablevalues, located in the main class, MainViewController. I intend to use the array in BillTrackerViewController as data for the UITableView there. However, when I try to set the value of that array, table_items, and segue, the table doesn't show anything. However, the value of billtrackertablevalues is properly filled, and is NOT null.

Here is my code for MainViewController:

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"toBillTracker"]) {
    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Resolution"];
    [query whereKey:@"event" equalTo:event_name_label.text];
    [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
            for (PFObject *object in objects) {
                [billtrackertablevalues addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\nPro: %@\nCon: %@\nResult: %@",[object objectForKey:@"resolution_name"], [object objectForKey:@"resolution_pro_speaker"], [object objectForKey:@"resolution_con_speaker"], [object objectForKey:@"resolution_result_id"]]];
            }
            NSLog(@"%@", billtrackertablevalues);

        } else {
            NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        }
    }];

    BillTrackerViewController *controller=(BillTrackerViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
    controller.table_items = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    controller.table_items = billtrackertablevalues;
}
}
```

And here is my code for BillTrackerViewController:

```
#import "BillTrackerViewController.h"
#import "Parse/Parse.h"

@interface BillTrackerViewController ()

@end

@implementation BillTrackerViewController

@synthesize billView;
@synthesize refreshButton;

@synthesize table_items;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
[billView reloadData];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
if (self) { }
return self;
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
return [table_items count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MainCell"];

if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"MainCell"];
}

NSString *cellText = table_items[indexPath.row];
cell.textLabel.text = cellText;
return cell;
}

@end
```

Once again, the table on BillTrackerViewController doesn't load values, but my initial array, billtrackertablevalues, is filled.

Thanks in advance, guys!

Comment: Check the value of billtrackertablevalues just before your last line in prepareForSegue. I think this is a timing issue -- the method, findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock: might be returning immediately before the block code executes. Also, this line, controller.table_items = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];, is useless and should be removed.

Comment: See answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20158584/952440 May be it will helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to move the lines instantiating controller, and setting its property to inside the block method:

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
    if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"toBillTracker"]) {
        PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Resolution"];
        [query whereKey:@"event" equalTo:event_name_label.text];
        [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
            for (PFObject *object in objects) {
                [billtrackertablevalues addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\nPro: %@\nCon: %@\nResult: %@",[object objectForKey:@"resolution_name"], [object objectForKey:@"resolution_pro_speaker"], [object objectForKey:@"resolution_con_speaker"], [object objectForKey:@"resolution_result_id"]]];
            }
            NSLog(@"%@", billtrackertablevalues);
            BillTrackerViewController *controller=(BillTrackerViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
            controller.table_items = billtrackertablevalues;

        } else {
            NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        }
        }];
    }
}
```

**After Edit:**

There is still a timing issue because the segue happens before the block returns, so you should override the setter for table_items in the BillTrackerViewController. The segue will still occur first (you might want to put a spinner in your view so the user knows something is happening), and then when the block finishes, the setter will be called:

```
-(void)setTable_items:(NSString *)table_items {
    _table_items = table_items;
    //update your table here.
}
```

Comment: still doesn't work - is there something I need to do on the other view controller?

Comment: @user2520999, does the log still show the correct values for billtrackertablevalues? Did you try logging controller and also controller.table_items (in prepareForSegue)? If not, do that, and report the results.

Comment: the log returned the following: (
    "Resolved, that you are what you eat.\nPro: Ryan Chiu\nCon: Sunny Shah\nResult: Passed",
    "Resolved, that modern technology has created a \"Me, Me, Me\" generation.\nPro: Ryan Chiu\nCon: Ryan Chiu\nResult: Failed"
)

Comment: did you want me to try putting the log at the end of the findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock: statement? (after "}];")

Comment: @user2520999, no, right after controller.table_items = billtrackertablevalues. But did you log controller and controller.table_items also?

Comment: @user2520999, I updated my answer to fix another timing issue. I thought this might be a problem, but I wanted to test it first.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
controller.table_items = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:billtrackertablevalues];
```

Also the problem might be in the `BillTrackerViewController` itself