# Segue Won't Pass Data

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, uitableview

I am trying to set an array in another view controller, named BillTrackerViewController, to the values of an NSMutableArray called billtrackertablevalues, located in the main class, MainViewController. I intend to use the array in BillTrackerViewController as data for the UITableView there. However, when I try to set the value of that array, table_items, and segue, the table doesn't show anything. However, the value of billtrackertablevalues is properly filled, and is NOT null.

Here is my code for MainViewController:

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
    if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"toBillTracker"]) {
        PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Resolution"];
        [query whereKey:@"event" equalTo:event_name_label.text];
        [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
            if (!error) {
                for (PFObject *object in objects) {
                    [billtrackertablevalues addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\nPro: %@\nCon: %@\nResult: %@",[object objectForKey:@"resolution_name"], [object objectForKey:@"resolution_pro_speaker"], [object objectForKey:@"resolution_con_speaker"], [object objectForKey:@"resolution_result_id"]]];
                }
                NSLog(@"%@", billtrackertablevalues);
                BillTrackerViewController *controller=(BillTrackerViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
                controller.table_items = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
                controller.table_items = billtrackertablevalues;
            } else {
                NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
            }
        }]; 
    }
}
```

And here is my code for BillTrackerViewController:

```
#import "BillTrackerViewController.h"
#import "Parse/Parse.h"

@interface BillTrackerViewController ()

@end

@implementation BillTrackerViewController

@synthesize billView;
@synthesize refreshButton;

@synthesize table_items;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [billView reloadData];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) { }
    return self;
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [table_items count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MainCell"];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"MainCell"];
    }

    NSString *cellText = table_items[indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = cellText;
    return cell;
}

@end
```

Once again, the table on BillTrackerViewController doesn't load values, but my initial array, billtrackertablevalues, is filled.

Thanks in advance, guys!

Comment: You shouldn't post this same question twice. I have answered this in your first post.

Answer (score 1):

Change the following code:-

```
controller.table_items = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
controller.table_items = billtrackertablevalues;
```

as like following:-

```
controller.table_items = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:billtrackertablevalues];
```

After that do `NSLog` at BillTrackerViewController in viewDidLoad method and let me know. Hope it will work.

Comment: After putting an NSLog in BillTrackerViewController in the viewDidLoad method, it returned "(null)," even though the billtrackertablevalues array in MainViewController was populated. However, the log from BillTrackerViewController came before the log for the billtrackertablevalues array, which might indicate a timing issue on the execution of the two methods.

Comment: @user2520999 Hmmm, Its cause timing issue, because you set array in block method here. You have to first execute PFQuery block method then you have to performSegue method.